# Why do I get an Access Denied error when creating an X509Certificate2 object?

Tags: .net, x509certificate, x509certificate2

We have some unit tests which have PFX certificates embedded in them.  These certificates are read during test execution and turned into `X509Certificate2` objects.  Unfortunately, when run as an unprivileged user, we get `Access Denied` exceptions:

```
using (var s = EmbeddedResourceUtilities.GetEmbeddedResourceAsStream(typeThatContainsEmbeddedResource, certFileName))
{
    if (s == null)
    {

        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Embedded certificate {0} for type {1} not found.", certFileName, typeThatContainsEmbeddedResource.FullName));
    }

    try
    {
        var bytes = new byte[s.Length];
        s.Read(bytes, 0, (int)s.Length);
        return new X509Certificate2(bytes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Error loading embedded certificate {0} for type {1}.", certFileName, typeThatContainsEmbeddedResource.FullName), ex);
    }
}
```

Here's the exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Access denied.
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
>     at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
>     at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
>     at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData)

I've tried modifying the constructor to use an empty password and explicit keyset flags, but that doesn't fix it:

```
// this doesn't work, either
return new X509Certificate2(bytes, String.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

I've read elsewhere that I should give my unprivileged user increased permissions on the MachineKeys directory, but I'm loathe to do that as it would allow production code to assume those permissions are available on that directory outside the test environment.

**Is there any way of allowing an unprivileged user to load an X509Certificate from a file?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my best guess about what's going on.

The X509Certificate2 constructor creates temporary public/private key objects in the Machine Keys directory (I believe via the Windows local security authority).  Because the our unprivileged user doesn’t have access to these keys or the Machine Keys directory, the tests fail.

Our solution was to update our environment setup scripts to install these test certificates ahead of time, grant the unprivileged user permissions to them, and re-write the tests to load the certificates from the appropriate certificate store.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you provide an example? Thank you

Answer (score 31):

Using the "X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet" flag in the X509Certificate2 constructor helped me.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer as it avoids having to mess around with the machine cert stores.

Comment: This one helped me! I did first mess around with the MachineKeys folder permissions but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I had were two others.
On the Latest windows version 2019 I think, and Windows 10, it is possible to have a pfx encoded certificate to be encrypted as TripleDES-SHA1 and also as AES256-SHA256.
On older windows versions, this even if the  password is correct, will fail with 'access denied'.

Another reason is that intermediate and root authority, could be non existent in the certificate store. Make sure you import them first via an import from .p7b to the local machine. Now the certificate will be marked as valid for serving SSL (e.g.) and 'Access Denied' is no  longer happening.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is specify the X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet flag

X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2("YourKey.pfx", "yourPassword",                                                                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);